# Using Lambda to filter by object member and a second integer array

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an array of integers:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
```

I also have an array of a custom object that contains an integer. I want to filter the array of custom objects using Lambda to only those matching integers in the numbers array above.

```
public class SomeStruct
{
    public int MyNumber;
}

ArrayOfSomeStruct = ArrayOfSomeStruct
    .Where(m = m.MyNumber is contained in numbers array);
```

How is this done?

Comment: Change numbers into a HashSet and then use HashSet.Contains in the Where.

Comment: `numbers.Contains(m.MyNumber)` should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like that:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
var numbersSet = numbers.ToHashset(); // for performance reason
var filtered = arrayOfSomeStruct.Where(e => numbersSet.Contains(e.MyNumber));
```

Answer (score 3):

Following your example, I've created an example [here](http://rextester.com/XUT69637)

This is the code that would get the elements of your array if their number is contained within your "number" variable.

```
ArrayOfSomeStruct = ArrayOfSomeStruct.Where(x => numbers.Contains(x.MyNumber)).ToArray();
```